# How to compare word frequencies from two text files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, frequency, word-frequency

How to compare word frequencies from two text files in python? For example, if a word contains in file1 and file2 both then it should be written only once but not adding their frequencies while comparing, it should be {'The': 3,5}. Here 3 is the frequency in file1 and 5 is frequency in file2. And if some words only exist in one file but not both then for that file there should be 0. Please Help
Here is what I have done so far:

```
import operator
f1=open('file1.txt','r') #file 1
f2=open('file2.txt','r') #file 2

wordlist=[]
wordlist2=[]
for line in f1:
    for word in line.split():
        wordlist.append(word)

for line in f2:
    for word in line.split():
        wordlist2.append(word)

worddictionary = {}
for word in wordlist:
    if word in worddictionary:
        worddictionary[word] += 1
    else:
        worddictionary[word] = 1

worddictionary2 = {}
for word in wordlist2:
    if word in worddictionary2:
        worddictionary2[word] += 1
    else:
        worddictionary2[word] = 1

print(worddictionary)
print(worddictionary2)
```

Comment: And what's wrong with what you have?

Comment: How to generalize it for more than 2 files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Here's the more general way you would do this for any list of files (explanation in comments):

```
f1=open('file1.txt','r') #file 1
f2=open('file2.txt','r') #file 2

file_list = [f1, f2] # This would hold all your open files
num_files = len(file_list)

frequencies = {} # We'll just make one dictionary to hold the frequencies

for i, f in enumerate(file_list): # Loop over the files, keeping an index i
    for line in f: # Get the lines of that file
        for word in line.split(): # Get the words of that file
            if not word in frequencies:
                frequencies[word] = [0 for _ in range(num_files)] # make a list of 0's for any word you haven't seen yet -- one 0 for each file

            frequencies[word][i] += 1 # Increment the frequency count for that word and file

print frequencies
```

Keeping with the code you wrote, here's how you could create a combined dictionary:

```
import operator
f1=open('file1.txt','r') #file 1
f2=open('file2.txt','r') #file 2

wordlist=[]
wordlist2=[]
for line in f1:
    for word in line.split():
        wordlist.append(word)

for line in f2:
    for word in line.split():
        wordlist2.append(word)

worddictionary = {}
for word in wordlist:
    if word in worddictionary:
        worddictionary[word] += 1
    else:
        worddictionary[word] = 1

worddictionary2 = {}
for word in wordlist2:
    if word in worddictionary2:
        worddictionary2[word] += 1
    else:
        worddictionary2[word] = 1

# Create a combined dictionary
combined_dictionary = {}
all_word_set = set(worddictionary.keys()) | set(worddictionary2.keys())
for word in all_word_set:
    combined_dictionary[word] = [0,0]
    if word in worddictionary:
        combined_dictionary[word][0] = worddictionary[word]
    if word in worddictionary2:
        combined_dictionary[word][1] = worddictionary2[word]


print(worddictionary)
print(worddictionary2)
print(combined_dictionary)
```

Comment: Thanks alot
is there any way that i can generalize it? for now it will only work for 2 files but what if i have to compare more than 2?

Comment: Definitely. I'll post a more general approach in a bit.

Comment: and Please can you add some explanations with it also? it will be very helpful for me

Comment: Since Im new to stack overflow therefore i was just checking its features.
I apologize

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misunderstood the problem, the code now works for your question.

```
f1 = open('file1.txt','r') #file 1
f2 = open('file2.txt','r') #file 2

wordList = {}

for line in f1.readlines(): #for each line in lines (file.readlines() returns a list)
    for word in line.split(): #for each word in each line
        if(not word in wordList): #if the word is not already in our dictionary
            wordList[word] = 0 #Add the word to the dictionary

for line in f2.readlines(): #for each line in lines (file.readlines() returns a list)
    for word in line.split(): #for each word in each line
        if(word in wordList): #if the word is already in our dictionary
            wordList[word] = wordList[word]+1 #add one to it's value

f1.close() #close files
f2.close()

f1 = open('file1.txt','r') #Have to re-open because we are at the end of the file.
#might be a n easier way of doing this

for line in f1.readlines(): #Removing keys whose values are 0
    for word in line.split(): #for each word in each line
        try:
            if(wordList[word] == 0): #if it's value is 0
                del wordList[word] #remove it from the dictionary
            else:
                wordList[word] = wordList[word]+1 #if it's value is not 0, add one to it for each occurrence in file1
        except:
            pass #we know the error was that there was no wordList[word]
f1.close()

print(wordList)
```

Adding first file words, if that word is in second file, add one to the value.
After that, check each word, if it's value is 0, remove it.

This can't be done by iterating over the dictionary, because it is changing size while iterating over it.

This is how you would implement it for multiple files (more complex):

```
f1 = open('file1.txt','r') #file 1
f2 = open('file2.txt','r') #file 2

fileList = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]
openList = []
for i in range(len(fileList)):
    openList.append(open(fileList[i], 'r'))

fileWords = []

for i, file in enumerate(openList): #for each file
    fileWords.append({}) #add a dictionary to our list
    for line in file: #for each line in each file
        for word in line.split(): #for each word in each line
            if(word in fileWords[i]): #if the word is already in our dictionary
                fileWords[i][word] += 1 #add one to it
            else:
                fileWords[i][word] = 1 #add it to our dictionary with value 0

for i in openList:
    i.close()

for i, wL in enumerate(fileWords):
    print(f"File: {fileList[i]}")
    for l in wL.items():
        print(l)
    #print(f"File {i}\n{wL}")
```

Comment: Please can you explain it but further? Im a beginner at python, therefore its little hard for me to understand

Comment: thank you but its not working.
giving a KeyError at  "if(wordList[word] == 0)"

Answer (score 0):

You might find the following demonstration program to be a good starting point for getting the word frequencies of your files:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import collections
import pathlib
import pprint
import re
import sys


def main():
    freq = get_freq(sys.argv[0])
    pprint.pprint(freq)


def get_freq(path):
    if isinstance(path, str):
        path = pathlib.Path(path)
    return collections.Counter(
        match.group() for match in re.finditer(r'\b\w+\b', path.open().read())
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In particular, you will want to use the `get_freq` function to get a `Counter` object that tells you what the word frequencies are. Your program can call the `get_freq` function multiple times with different file names, and you should find the `Counter` objects to be very similar to the dictionaries you were previously using.